# Smallest $x$ that allows for division by $y$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Assume we know $y$ which is prime of form $6k+1$ (may not be relevant). I want a simplified way to find the smallest positive $x$ where $y$ divides $x^2-x+1$. Is there a better way than just testing $x=1, 2, 3$ etc?

Comment: Have you noticed that both solutions for $x$ are primitive sixth roots of unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a value of $x$ that satisfies

$$
x^2-x+1 \equiv 0 \mod 6k+1
$$
where $6k+1$ is a prime number. Now, we can complete the square to get

$$
\left(x-\frac12\right)^2 = x^2-x+\frac14\equiv -\frac34 \mod 6k+1
$$
So there can only be a solution if $-3$ is a quadratic residue mod $6k+1$. As it happens, for all primes of that form, $-3$ is a quadratic residue.

Now, you can use any of the modular square root algorithms, like Tonelli-Shanks, to find $\sqrt{-3}$. If $m\equiv \sqrt{-3}$, then you have

$$
x \equiv \frac{m+1}2 \mod 6k+1
$$

Now, let's look at an example of using this. Consider the case of $k=10$, so $y=61$, a prime. You're looking for solutions to

$$
m^2 \equiv -3 \mod 61
$$
Generally, you'd use Tonelli-Shanks or another modular square root algorithm, but I'll skip those details - the two solutions are $m\equiv27$ and $m\equiv34$.

Now, we have $x\equiv 14$ and $x\equiv \frac{35}{2} \equiv 48$.

So our smallest $x$ such that $x^2-x+1|y$ is $x=14$. $14^2-14+1 = 183 = 3\cdot 61$.

Comment: I am sorry; I am not sure I quite understand. How does this help find the smallest x any faster than the current approach?

Comment: Because you can use any of the modular square root algorithms, like Tonelli-Shanks, to compute the square root.

Comment: Seems to be for x^2 cases not x http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm

Comment: Modular square root algorithms solve $x^2\equiv a$, which is useful, because you have $m^2\equiv -3$.

Comment: I am trying to find smallest x^2-x+1 that is divisible by (known) y

Comment: Yes, and to do it without brute forcing it, you need to use modular arithmetic. If $a|b$, then $b\equiv 0 \pmod a$.

Comment: Yes, I know that much is true, but I don't understand how this answer applies (I'm not a math major or anything like that; I need things dumbed down for me a bit)

Comment: This answer finds solutions to the problem. There will be two values of $m$, giving you two values for $x$. The smaller of the two is obviously the answer you seek. (Keep in mind that one of them will be odd, so you have to multiply by $3k+1$ rather than dividing by 2)

Comment: Can you provide an example perhaps so I can better understand what your answer is trying to say?

Comment: OK, I'll add an example to the solution. Give me a minute or two.

Comment: @Aruka: The short form of this answer says "use the quadratic formula (or other similar methods) to solve quadratic equations".

Comment: Where did 11 come from? And 35/2 = 48?

Comment: 11 was a typo, fixing it now. 35/2 is 48 because $48\cdot2 = 96 \equiv 96-61 = 35$.

Comment: @GlenO If I wanted to extrapolate this to other x-polynomials, is there something I can look up to learn about how to find that "quadratic residue"? In this case your target was -3 given the nature of x and the form of the prime. If you want I can make this a new question (although I am not sure how to word it)

Comment: If it's a quadratic equation, then as Hurkyl correctly points out, it's just the quadratic equation, and you evaluate the square root by using a modular square root algorithm (Wikipedia has pages on three different such algorithms). If it's higher order, then, just as with regular polynomials, it gets more complicated.

Comment: Also worth noting is that the form of the polynomial and the prime means that sometimes the polynomial is irreducible. For instance, there is no integer $x$ such that $x^2-x+1$ is divisible by 5, because $-3\equiv 2$ isn't a quadratic residue mod 5.